# React Native - Appium Studio shows previous screen components in view heirarchy on Android when navigating to new screen

Tags: android, react-native, appium, appium-android

When using Appium Studio on our React Native project it works fine for an initial screen on a stack.  When we navigate to a new screen in the stack the component heirarchy in the object spy shows every component on every previous screen, as well as the new screen components.

This makes it impossible to re-use accessibility labels as the automated tests are picking up labels on previous screens, not the current screen, as they are higher in the view heirarchy, making testing extremely difficult.

On iOS we don't have this problem.  The object spy doesn't show components on previous screens.

Does anyone know a solution to make Appium only see the components on the current screen on Android?